# Error in google colab "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:"

Tags: python, arrays

`I get error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
I think my problem is inverse_transform`

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Pos.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
print(X)
print(y)
y = y.reshape(len(y),1)
print(y)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
print(X)
print(y)

# Training the SVR model on the whole dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))

# Visualising the SVR results
plt.scatter(sc_X.inverse_transform(X), sc_y.inverse_transform(y), color = 'red')
plt.plot(sc_X.inverse_transform(X), sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(X)), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Comment: looks like a problem with the `dataset` so that are to contents of the `Pos.csv` file please ?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/akram24/position-salaries    @D.L

Answer (score 0):

okay,  so fist of all create a sample CSV as per the link.

Then push this into a dataframe.

```py
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
csv_file = 'G:\\MyDrive\\path\\to\\test_output.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# the dataset
print(dataset)
```

at this point inspect the data: `print(dataset)`

The data should look like this:

```
            position  level   salary
0   Business Analyst      1    45000
2  Senior Consultant      3    60000
3            Manager      4    80000
4    Country Manager      5   110000
5     Region Manager      6   150000
6            Partner      7   200000
7     Senior Partner      8   300000
8            C-level      9   500000
9                CEO     10  1000000
```

The code in the question then tries to create two `lists`: `X` and `y`.

It should use the native dataframe which is more efficient and easier. So `X` and `y` will be this:

```py
my_x = [i+1 for i in range(len(dataset))]
my_y = dataset['salary'].values
```

...this produces have 2 lists:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[  45000   50000   60000   80000  110000  150000  200000  300000  500000
 1000000]
```

This is the answer so far.

So the new question is what do you want to achieve with the `reshape` line given there are two (same length) lists ?

Comment: Honestly, First of all, I'm very happy that you were interested in. However, my main goal is to scale this dataset and process it with support vector regression, then bring the data to its normal values ​​with inverse. I'm trying to learn the problem Which I can do it in different ways. But I am constantly getting the error as I mentioned in the inverse section. I'm really stuck.